# Now() in ColdFusion (Railo) ORM entity property as a default?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, railo

A common design I use is to set a date column with the current date as the default. For SQL Server I use getDate() and for MySQL now() or current_timestamp.

Implementing a MySQL solution in ORM, seemed the way to do it would be:

```
property name="dtSaved" ormtype="date" dbdefault="now()";
```

However, this isn't working, but isn't throwing an error either. When I run ORMReload(), it seems to get stuck on this table, and none of the entities that come after (alphabetically) get created. (I'm using dbcreate="dropcreate")

Note that this is Railo 3.3.1, not Adobe ColdFusion 9.

Comment: Have you considered doing it in the MySQL side, as a default value for the column there?

Comment: Did you try using current_timestampe instead of Now()?

Comment: @JakeFeasel I could do that, but I'm trying to keep all of the modeling in code. I could also use an event or override the setDtSaved() event, but I'd like to do it the "right" way

Comment: @JasonTabler Yes, I tried both, as well as using the timestamp ormType, with the same result

Comment: Hmm, there has to be something in the hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a dynamic default value in your constructor, so something like this:

```
component persistent="true" {
property name="measurementDate" ormtype="date";
function any init(){
if (IsNull(variables.measurementDate)){
variables.measurementDate = Now();
}
return this;
 }
}
```

Comment by John Whish – November 22, 2010

from: 
http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/coldfusion-9-orm-example-215